# Android realtime multiplayer game UDP Lag over wifi

Tags: java, android, networking, udp, lag

### Problem introduction

Hi, I am working on the realtime multiplayer module of my android game "Space Corsair".

It's UDP based, each device communicate with a central java server that handle the game logic. Clients send only player inputs and receive from server objects positions and events.

My first POC works fine on emulator, nexus 7 and HTC desire. With the same code version, I have some network issue with my nexus 4 (Sometimes it works and most of the time I am experiencing the problem) : Instead of reading continuously server packet, the n4 seems to buffer them and deliver them to my app in batch : huge problem for player experience.

### Network graphs

First screenshot : a normal rx/tx graph while playing the game

[image: normal rt/tx]

Second screenshot : anormal rt/tx, client receives all data in a spike

[image: problematic rt/tx]

### Test protocol

I run my tests in a local wifi network with 6 ms ping on working devices, I tried to increase the packet size (right now 508 bytes to ensure one packet is not chucked), to ping every 75 ms (instead of 500) to keep the connection up, I disabled wifi battery optimisation in the phone settings.

Strange fact when I usb upload a new version of the code 90% of the time if works fine. Then when i quit completely the game and start it again from the main screen I have the lag. I tried to reboot my nexus 4 but same problem on startup.

### Network code

Here is my reader thread

```
public class UDPHandler implements Runnable {

    private boolean running = false;
    public static final Integer PACKET_SIZE = 508;

    private final PacketRecievedListener listener;

    public UDPSender sender;

    public UDPHandler(PacketRecievedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.sender = new UDPSender();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {


        running = true;

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[PACKET_SIZE];

        DatagramSocket serverSocket = getLocalDatagramSocket();

        Logs.i("Udp with ip " + MultiUtils.getIPAddress(true) + " listening on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, PACKET_SIZE);

        while (running) {
            try {

                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                listener.onPacketRecieved(receivePacket.getData(), receivePacket.getAddress());
                receivePacket.setLength(PACKET_SIZE);

            } catch (SocketException e) {
                Logs.e("",e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logs.e("",e);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Used to bind reader to sender socket
     * Wait the sender to be ready and return the socket
     * @return
     */
    private DatagramSocket getLocalDatagramSocket() {


        while (UDPSender.socket == null) {

            try {
                Logs.i("Trying to obtain socket");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Logs.e("",e);
            }


        }
        return UDPSender.socket;
    }


    public void stop() {
        this.running = false;
    }


}
```

And the code to create the socket (reader reuse the sender socket)

```
public void initSocket(){


    if (socket == null){

        try {
            DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
            socket = channel.socket();
            socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(UDPSender.LOCAL_LISTENER_PORT));
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);


        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Logs.e("echec dans le socket",e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logs.e("echec dans le socket", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: have u figured out the reason/ solution?

Comment: sorry no, I stopped the multiplayer module for a while ;)